# I would like to remove it from the checkout page but It has required attribute how to remove it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, invokerequired

This is inside the checkout.page.blade I would like to remove the account creation form from the checkout page but the e-mail and password section has required attribute and it shows it is required at the front end even if i remove this part from the page.

```
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::email('email', Null, ['class' => 'form-control flat', 'placeholder' => trans('theme.placeholder.email'), 'maxlength' => '100', 'required']) !!}
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    {!! Form::checkbox('create-account', Null, Null, ['id' => 'create-account-checkbox', 'class' => 'i-check']) !!} {!! trans('theme.create_account') !!}
  </label>
</div>

<div id="create-account" class="space30" style="display: none;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding-right">
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control flat', 'id' => 'acc-password', 'placeholder' => trans('theme.placeholder.password'), 'data-minlength' => '6']) !!}
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 nopadding-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class' => 'form-control flat', 'placeholder' => trans('theme.placeholder.confirm_password'), 'data-match' => '#acc-password']) !!}
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to select a line and hit DELETE ..? Or is this a browser extension or a user script?

Comment: Hacks: You could statically set values for those require field and make them [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden). Also, you can hide the form instead of removing it using CSS [display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). However, it is best to be to alter the code requiring those fields so they're not required anymore.

Comment: if this is related to laravel blade, check your request handler and middlware. remove the validation logic for intended inputs.